# How do I filter Smarty variable to output only numbers?

Tags: regex, string, smarty

Fairly simple question, but I am new to regular expressions and smarty templates, and I can't seem to figure out how to get this working in my smarty template.

Basically, I have smarty string that can contain string values like:

```
Home Page Layout 1-1
Home Page Layout 1-2
Home Page Layout 2-1 
etc..
```

I want to extract just the integers from the string so that the output is as followed:

```
11
12
21
```

As you can see, I'm removing everything but the integers.  I tried doing the following after searching around, but it doesn't work or output anything.

```
{$SelectHomePageLayout|regex_replace:'[^0-9]+':''}
```

Fairly simple but I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the regex delimiter(i.e. `//`) for your regex. Use the following one, and check how the delimiter is added.

```
{$SelectHomePageLayout|regex_replace:'/[^0-9]+/':''}
                                      ^       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will also allow floating numbers as well:

```
{$my_string|regex_replace:'/[^0-9,.]+/':''}
```